# Working with koa js routes and es6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, koa, es6-class

How do we access koa js route `context` (this) and es6 class `this` within a es6 class?

When i try to access class property using `this.name` i get **undefined**

test.js

```
export default class {
  constructor (opts) {
    this.name = 'test'
  }

  welcome () {
    console.log(this.name) // 'this' is UNDEFINED. Trying to access class property. But getting undefined
    this.body = 'welcome '+this.params.name // 'this' works fine here as a koa reference
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import test from './test'
let Test = new test({})

router.get('/test/:name', Test.welcome)
```

Comment: Context is lost when you passing callback as parameter like `Test.welcome`. Just use `() => Test.welcome()` instead.

Comment: Your capitalisation is odd. Classes should be uppercase, instances lowercase.

Comment: Use `router.get('/test/:name', function() { Test.welcome(this) })` and add a `context` parameter to your method

Comment: @Bergi router.get('/test/:name', function () { Test.welcome(this) }) this work perfectly. But using es6 fat arrow give 'this' as undefined
router.get('/test/:name', () => { Test.welcome(this) } ) any idea? This is not my actual code. I have better casing in actual code :-)

Comment: @sravis Yes, [that's expected](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572). Though I can't really believe that koa routers rely on the `this` keyword

Comment: Koa itself uses `this` in its middleware for the first version. Koa v2 uses `async` arrow functions with `ctx` passed to the arrow function as the first argument. Even if you're not using Koa 2 with `async` (which requires `babel`), I believe you can just do something like this currently: `router.get('/', (ctx) => { ... });`

Comment: @Andrey you save my life :D

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the class declaration and export syntax you're using and I'm thinking that might be the issue.

Something like this should work (note that this code works with require but it should be just the same with `import`):

test.js

```
class test{
    constructor(opts) {
        this.name = 'test';
    }

    welcome() {
        console.log(this.name); // 'this' is UNDEFINED. Trying to access class property. But getting undefined
        this.body = 'welcome ' + this.params.name; // 'this' works fine here as a koa reference
    }
}

module.exports = test;
```

app.js

```
let test = require('./test');
let Test = new test({});

Test.welcome();
```

While this code shows `this.name` perfectly fine, it breaks on `this.params`, which I assume you have declared elsewhere.